# How to redirect site to 403 if a certain url get variable exists or contains an unwanted value using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my site statistics, I'm staring to get strange URLs like these:

```
mysite.com/?p=casino-online-spielen

mysite.com/category/page/2/?p=casino-online-spielen
```

I've tried rewrites but it has messed up my WordPress rewrites or just didn't work. I am not that good in htaccess or apache.

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 ?p=(casino|pharmacy)
</IfModule>
```

What I need is a htaccess rule that sends the user to 403 error if the word casino is found, or better yet if ?p= is found in the URL, which is not supposed to happen. But I fear it will destroy archive pagination.

On the other hand, it should allows ?s= variables and whatever is in it.

Comment: With mod_alias you can't match against query strings in urls, use mod_rewrite.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2):

Essentially follow @Starkeen suggestion and use mod_rewrite eg.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(casino|pharmacy) 
  RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note:

- F = Forbidden = 403
- L = Last = Just doooooo IT.

Comment: Tried this, sadly, didn't work. It did not redirect to 403 error.  I'll be reading up on mod_rewrite, and thanks for your input.

(It either removes the p query string totally, or ignores it. Also I am using WordPress)