# How to Stop Fake Traffic Bot with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am worried about my website because of Some fake traffic showing in analytics social/Facebook, but in detail, bot picks fake wrong URL on my site randomly like this `example.com/page?=__HzoblPdx` but actual URL is `example.com/page/HzoblPdx/title-title`. I want to block this link `page?=__HzoblPdx.`

Anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you'll be better off asking this question in serverfault instead. Does not seem a question related to programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that quite easily by using the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain\.com/page\?=__HzoblPdx [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} www\.domain\.com/page\?=__HzoblPdx [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This will block access to any bots trying to access through that domain. Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: bro this id change randomly not fixed `__HzoblPdx`

Comment: Should have specified that in your question. Change it to `page?=$1`

Comment: Does it always add `__` on to the URL before the variable?

Comment: yes i check always in analytics single or double underscore

Comment: but bro i checked without __ not working can i chat with you private if i can then how

Comment: When you say it is not working, what happens? Are you get an internal server error or nothing happens at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152737/discussion-between-alish-and-lag).

Comment: plz check private msg

Answer (score 1):

Check the apache access logs and check the user agent string of the visitor trying to access the non existant page. You can use robots.txt to block certain user agents altogether.

You can get lots of info on robots.txt from google. Here's one site all about it that you can have a read of. http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: this is a plus, but not really a solution: robots.txt is informative, not an interdiction. Bots can perfectly choose to ignore what's in the file.

Comment: i can agree with that.

Comment: Lag has the htaccess answer. I would use both!

Comment: yes, robots.txt is very useful, "good bots" follow what's in them.. just wanted to precise that it won't stop malicious ones

Comment: i want to show forbidden 403 error when some one try to use my site with this type of link domain/page?=HzoblPdx

Comment: Alish, have a look here :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036831/how-to-redirect-site-to-403-if-a-certain-url-get-variable-exists-or-contains-an

Comment: @delboy1978uk You're right. Using both would be better - I'd do the same. I don't think the OP is interested however, seemed to only want a quick answer to his immediate problem. Meh.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using mod_rewrite, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^=_
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This blocks (403 Forbidden) any requested URL that contains a query string that starts `=_`.

Although, the fact that this URL parameter maps to the real URL looks like it might be a misconfiguration error, which the bots have been able to find?